# android: App crashes when calling method in Main activity from custom activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to build a quiz-like app for guessing flags in android. Basically i have an activity named *SetFlagActivity* which receivs intent from the *startFlagActivity(View v)* in MainActivity if a button is clicked . It needs to do two things: # 1 if the user inputs correct name of the flag load a new flag and # 2 display message: "correct" else just display "wrong".

When the button is pressed the correct message is displayed, but the ImageView containing the image of the flag disappears. Also when the button is clicked again application crashes with following [output:](http://pastebin.com/GRvThXyk)

I assumed that image doesn't appear because it's displayed in MainActivity, so i used *finish()* to go back. That fixed the app crashing, but again when i click the button nothing happens...no message is displayed. So the question is how do i use SetFlagActivity in a correct way that it displays my message and sets a new image..

Any help will be apreciated.

This gets the input and sends an intent

```
public void startFlagActivity(View v){
    EditText flagInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputFlag);
    String message = flagInput.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetFlagActivity.class);
    if(!message.equals(""))
        intent.putExtra("flag", message);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

And my SetFlagActivity looks like this:

```
package ivve.projects.flags;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SetFlagActivity extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startFlagActivity(v);
        }
    });
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayAnswer); 
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("flag"); 
        if(value.equals("Iceland")){
            text.setText("correct");
        }
        else{
            text.setText("wrong"); 
        }
    finish();
    }
}
```

Edit1: StartFlagActivity is actually not an activity by itself...it is a function inside the MainActivity
Edit2: I have added the onClick handler to my SetFlagActivity as suggested, but i get an error "*The method startFlagActivity(View) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}*" which doesn't allow me to call to startFlagActivity method

Comment: 'R.id.displayAnswer' this TextView belongs to which layout?. Also, I feel when u start the intent, the finish() happens inside oncreate(). This is really fast. You can try giving a wait-timer, like sleep() or wait(), just before finish for  1sec or something - to test your code.

Comment: I don't see any code related to the *image* you talk about??

Comment: R.id.displayAnswer belongs to activity_main.xml layout. Should i use the finish method in this activity or in the one where i am calling the intent?

Comment: You need to define the onClickListener method through startFlagActivity() as that is what you have set the onClick() method to.

Comment: Ahh.. I see what you've done now - I'll edit my answer and point you in the direction you need to go.

Comment: Done.. see my new update answer. Let me know if it how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared the button (id = button) in activity_main.xml and set the button's OnClickListener through the onClick attribute to refer to the startFlagActivity method. What you are trying to do is to check if the TextView contains the correct answer and if yes, then proceed else remain in this page. One suggestion off topic would be to initialize the TextView variable within onCreate(). Here while it works for you, you are re-initializing it every time you click.

You have now inflated this view in  MainActivity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml); // This inflates the layout.
// Now you dynamically have set the flag. This is not part of the activity_main.xml
```

You have declared startFlagActivity() in MainActivity() and the logic behind it is that the new Activity should be started (when the button is clicked) with the answer passed in as a parameter to the intent. The newly started intent will check if the answer is correct and if yes, will display correct.

Now to answer your first question that the image view disappears. This happens because you have inflated activity_main.xml - but the ImageView was created dynamically in MainActivity and does not exist in SetFlagActivity (there basically is no image in this screen). This is why the map disappears but you see the rest of the layout as it remains the same.

Then, when you again click the button, the onClick() method (or in this case the startFlagActivity() method) does not exist for the activity SetFlagActivity currently being displayed and that was why you received the error log that said that the onClick() method startFlagActivity() does not exist for the SetFlagActivity screen. I hope this makes sense. Clicking the button now will not produce anything as there is no code to back it up (also produces error logs). I hope you see now where your logic is flawed.

You don't need to start a new activity. You can finish it off based on if-else conditions. Your algorithm would be:

```
If (answer = correct)
    setImageView -> new drawable;
    repeat process;
else
    show wrong and repeat;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: startFlagActivity actually IS the button's onClick event function. Button is defined in my main.xml and this android:onClick = "startFlagActivity"

Comment: From the logs you had posted, the app expects startFlagActivity(View) to be present in SetFlagActivity()  - but it is not in that correct?. You have expanded activity_main on SetFlagActivity. If this button is present in activity_main.xml, then SetFlagActivity should have the method startFlagActivity(). Can you shows us activity_main.xml?

Comment: Here is my activity_main.xml...as i said the button is defined here http://pastebin.com/XCSHw4Ni

Comment: I edited the answer. You have removed the logs.. can you try out what I posted and see what logs you receive?

Comment: Can you explain about button click handler a bit more? i'm bit confused...if i define button listener in SetFlagActivity what would it do...and i would still have to call this activity from somewhere if the button is clicked?

Comment: Ok, i have implemented the OnClick handler in SetFlagActivity as you suggested, but somehow when i try to call startFlagActivity from onClick handler and passing view to it, i get an error: "The method startFlagActivity(View) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}". I will edit my post to add this bit of code.

Comment: Can you post a link like before where you have listed out your MainActivity as well? I think you have made an application logic error somewhere. What is the layout you are inflating in setContentView() n MainActivity. Any activity which inflate activity_main.xml should implement the onClickListener because you have set the onClick() attribute in main.xml. If you can show your MainActivity, I can re-edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, @Sunil here is my complete code: [MainActivity](http://pastebin.com/N33wM7W4) and [SetFlagActivity](http://pastebin.com/N33wM7W4)

Comment: Thank you very much, i've updated my code so everything is a part of the same layout...i've managed to display a new image when the user guesses the flag name, now i just have to figure out how to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
03-08 20:52:59.539: E/AndroidRuntime(9399): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method startFlagActivity(View) in the activity class ivve.projects.flags.SetFlagActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button'
03-08 20:52:59.539: E/AndroidRuntime(9399):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2131)
```

you forgot to declare  `startFlagActivity(View)` inside `SetFlagActivity`. Maybe you have set the wrong layout in `SetFlagActivity`

Comment: Is it always the case that i have to declare in the activity that is being called the one that is calling it? And how would you do it? Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to say that it's a bit weird that i have to declare in my current activity the one that just called it...